# Spring Boot V 2.4.0 Using DaoAuthenticationProvider SHA-512

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, sha512, spring5

In spring 5 + the encryption type SHA-512 is deprecated. In my API project, I'm using the spring 5+, I have to use SHA-512 as the DB is old type password encryption. My encoder method needs to return a custom class object that encodes to SHA-512 with user email as salt. I'm using a custom user table.
Any idea of how to deal with this situation?
Thanks for the help guys. My spring security class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private final CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
@Autowired
public SecurityConfig(CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService{this.customUserDetailsService=customUserDetailsService;}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
    return authProvider;
}
@Bean
public DelegatingPasswordEncoder encoder() {//what i return here for SHA-512?;}
}
```